# Kendo UI grid command firing multiple functions from different command buttons

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo UI grid with 3 command buttons on it:

```
$('#Grid').kendoGrid({
    columns: [{
        field: "Data1",
    },
    {
        field: "Data2"
    },
    {
    command: [{
        text: " ",
        click: testFunction,
        iconClass: "fa fa-align-justify"
    },
    {
        text: " ",
        click: testFunction2,
        iconClass: "fa fa-code"
     },
     {
         text: " ",
         click: testFunction3,
         iconClass: "fa fa-database"
     }]
     }],
     dataSource: {
          pageSize: 10,
          data: data
     }
});
```

With these functions:

```
testFunction: function () {
    alert("testFunction");
},

testFunction2: function () {
    alert("testFunction2");
},

testFunction3: function () {
    alert("testFunction3");
}
```

But when I click one of the command buttons all 3 of the functions get fired.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Is there any way to prevent this behaviour so only the function connected to the button clicked fires?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a [`name`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.command#columns.command.name) property to each command button, e.g.:

```
command: [{
    text: " ",
    click: testFunction,
    iconClass: "fa fa-align-justify",
    name: "btn1"
}
```

[Demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/UTEtAxox):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      var testFunction= function () {
        alert("testFunction");
      },

      testFunction2= function () {
          alert("testFunction2");
      },

      testFunction3= function () {
          alert("testFunction3");
      };
      
      $('#Grid').kendoGrid({
          columns: [{
              field: "Data1",
          },
          {
              field: "Data2"
          },
          {
          command: [{
              text: " ",
              click: testFunction,
              iconClass: "fa fa-align-justify",
            name: "btn1"
          },
          {
              text: " ",
              click: testFunction2,
              iconClass: "fa fa-code",
            name: "btn2"
           },
           {
               text: " ",
               click: testFunction3,
               iconClass: "fa fa-database",
            name: "btn3"
           }]
          }],
        dataSource: {
          pageSize: 10,
          data: [{a: 1}]
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="Grid"></div>
</body>
</html>
```